# How to implement a sidebar that is bound to the route in nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

so I structured my pages folder like this

```
pages/
--index/
----page1/
------_slug.vue
----page2/
------_slug.vue
----page1.vue // contains different content
----page2.vue // contains different content
--index.vue
```

so the routes can be accessed like

- `/index`
- `/index/page1`
- `/index/page2`
- `/index/page1/some-slug-here`
- `/index/page2/some-slug-here`

now, what I want to achieve is, when I access the route `/index/page2/some-slug-here`. it will show the sidebar component based on that route param.
so to show some visual, take a look at the attached image.

since nuxt don't seem to support named view routes. are there any other ways to achieve what I want?

thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt.js does support named views. They are referenced as `layouts` in [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views#layouts) and serve exactly that purpose.

It is possible to create multiple `layouts` in `layouts` folder and specify them for each page as following:

```
<template>
  <!-- Your template -->
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    layout: 'sidebar'
    // page component definitions
  }
</script>
```